# Unable to do sum and getting same value by using while loop php

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, sum

I'm working on project where I'm preparing a large array set to create a function that will save the value into the database one by one.

So that I created a loop to generate the array as plain text format that I need

```
$i = 1;
while( $i <= 65 ) {
  $startVal = $this->summe(35501, 500);
  $endVal = $this->summe(36000, 500);
  $amount = $this->summe(3575, 50);
  echo "array(<br>";
    echo "'low'     => '".$startVal."',<br>";
    echo "'high'    => '".$endVal."',<br>";
    echo "'amount'  => '".$amount."',<br>";
    echo '\'city\'    => $city<br>';
  echo "),<br>";
  $i++;
}
```

**But there is a small issue that whenever I run the code, every time loop return same value:**

```
array(
'low' => '36001',
'high' => '36500',
'amount' => '3625',
'city' => $city
),
array(
'low' => '36001',
'high' => '36500',
'amount' => '3625',
'city' => $city
),
array(
'low' => '36001',
'high' => '36500',
'amount' => '3625',
'city' => $city
),
array(
'low' => '36001',
'high' => '36500',
'amount' => '3625',
'city' => $city
),
```

**But I need to generate output like following format:**

```
array(
'low' => '36001', 
'high' => '36500',
'amount' => '3625',
'city' => $city
),
array(
'low' => '36501', // Adding 500
'high' => '37000', // Adding 500
'amount' => '3675', // Adding 50
'city' => $city
),
array(
'low' => '37001', // Adding 500
'high' => '37500', // Adding 500
'amount' => '3725', // Adding 50
'city' => $city
),
array(
'low' => '37501', // Adding 500
'high' => '38000', // Adding 500
'amount' => '3775', // Adding 50
'city' => $city
),
```

Comment: Well it would! As `you dont do any of that Addition

Comment: There should be `$this->summe(35501, 500 * $i)`

Comment: @user14717238 that would be valid as an alternative answer to mine

Comment: _“create a function that will save the value into the database one by one”_ - why does that require creating of the _PHP code_ for an array, _manually_?

Comment: @CBroe I'm working on ecom project where client need to create custom shipping charges table with predefined data whenever he enter city name in db 

there are two different table 
'Cities_opt_in' & 'shipping_charges'

Comment: @CodeGuruDev As far as I can see that doesn't really explain why specifically you need to output that `array( x => y)` formatted data from your loop. I pointed out in my answer as well that this was a fairly odd thing to do. If you need to put some data in the DB, then this code wouldn't really be much use for that specific task.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your suggestion bro I was working on project where I was creating custom shipping charges module. 

Admin wants that whenever he add a new city as delivery location where he deliver his goods, There should be add some default shipping charges table with each added new city.

so that's why I was used that method.

Comment: @ADyson the "Low" & "High" is the weight in grams so that he can later calculate the shipping charges according to the weight of goods by using city.

Comment: Thanks, but still, none of that justifies why you chose _this particular data format_ to store the data. JSON would be much simpler...that was my point. I don't disagree that you would need to store the data, my purpose was to point out that it's not a good format to store it in.

Comment: @ADyson thank you for your suggestion i'll keep it in mind for all my future projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're feeding the same hard-coded values to the `summe` function each time, so it's unsurprising that you get the same results each time. (I assume that function just adds the two numbers together, although you didn't show the code for it.)

If you want it to increment each time, then you need to keep a record of the value returned on the previous loop, and use that instead. Something like this:

```
$i = 1;
$startVal = 35501;
$endVal = 36000;
$amount = 3575;

while( $i <= 65 ) {
  $startVal = $this->summe($startVal, 500);
  $endVal = $this->summe($endVal, 500);
  $amount = $this->summe($amount, 50);
  echo "array(<br>";
    echo "'low'     => '".$startVal."',<br>";
    echo "'high'    => '".$endVal."',<br>";
    echo "'amount'  => '".$amount."',<br>";
    echo '\'city\'    => $city<br>';
  echo "),<br>";
  $i++;
}
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e8bcca803d8cac56b85d5ac7841d18250aca11e3

Also the `summe` function is redundant, you don't need to have a wrapper just for doing a trivial addition. Without the unncessary overhead of a function call, you could write the same 3 lines as

```
$startVal += 500;
$endVal += 500;
$amount += 50;
```

instead.

---

P.S. As an aside, you appear to be trying to use PHP to generate string output similar to that produced by `print_r()` - or perhaps more like `var_export()`. It's not clear why you're doing that rather than just using one of those debugging functions directly, or (if debugging isn't the objective) outputting to a recognised, standard, parseable format such as JSON or XML.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help I solve the mystery and credit goes to you thank you man for saving my life....

Comment: No problem, but was it really such a big mystery? if you repeatedly add the same numbers together you will repeatedly get the same results. it's not really clear why you thought the original code was likely to work. Or are you saying the mystery was how to make it increment by the correct amount each time? Anyway if the answer has heped you please remember to mark it as accepted - thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Now I got the answer and credit goes to @ADyson, Thank you so much

> **Here are the updated working code:**

```
$i = 1;
$var_startVal = 500;
$var_endVal = 500;
$var_amount = 50;

while( $i <= 65 ) {
  $var_startVal += 500;
  $var_endVal += 500;
  $var_amount += 50;

  $startVal = 35501, $var_startVal;
  $endVal = 36000, $var_endVal;
  $amount = 3575, $var_amount;
  echo "array(<br>";
    echo "'low'     => '".$startVal."',<br>";
    echo "'high'    => '".$endVal."',<br>";
    echo "'amount'  => '".$amount."',<br>";
    echo '\'city\'    => $city<br>';
  echo "),<br>";
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: done I marked your answer as accepted and thank you so much for all your help

When I execute your demo link I found some issue with your code  that both high and low value are same but I really appreciated for all your support and help

Comment: Thanks it was just a typo, I set $startVal and $endVal to the same initially - just a copy/paste error. I've corrected the answer and updated the demo link now.